# Is it ok to use strcpy() to copy a malloc array to a stack array in C?

Tags: c, memory

I'm wondering if it is okay to use the `strcpy()` function in C to copy a heap array to a stack array? Are there any potential problems to that?

Comment: The potential problems are similar to those copying in the reverse direction — mainly making sure you have enough space in the target for the source string.  When copying to the stack, you don't have to worry about whether the space was allocated; when copying the other way, you need to be sure that the allocation on the heap was successful.

Comment: Does the source array contain a string? Is the destination array large enough to hold the string and its terminator?

Comment: The question just says 'a heap array', hence my issue with the accepted answer which. somehow, accumulated 6 upvotes despite being, 'Of course it's okay', misleading/wrong:(

Comment: OK, VTC as 'unclear what you're asking' :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's okay to copy into a stack array.

To be clear, it would look like this:

```
char on_stack[100];
strcpy(on_stack, source_string_on_heap);
```

Just make sure that the stack array is big enough to hold what you're copying, and be aware that the stack array will disappear after its context ends. Never have a function return a pointer to a stack variable.

Note on `strcpy()` usage: Your source buffer must be null-terminated and your destination buffer must have room for the termination character as well. This has nothing to do with heap or stack usage, it's just how the `strcpy()` function works.

You are also free to use any other method to copy from the heap to the stack, including using `memcpy()` or manually copying byte-by-byte with a `char*` and loop.

Comment: Where does it say, in the question, that the source buffer contains a null-terminated.char array?

Comment: @MartinJames He asked specifically about `strcpy()`. He *better* have a null-terminated string.

Comment: It just says 'array'. Could be a null-terminated char array, or an array of ints, doubles or pointers to nasal demons;(

Comment: @MartinJames I interpreted his question as being that he already knows how to use `strcpy()` correctly, and wants to know if there are caveats specifically related to *heap* vs *stack* destinations. There aren't. Your answer doesn't mention the stack or heap, and therefor avoids his core question entirely. For what's it's worth, I was not the one that down-voted you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not OK:

1) Unless you can be sure that the source array is null-terminated, the copy may run out-of-bounds: UB.

2) If the source array contains data with embedded nulls, the copy will terminate before all the required data is copied.

3) There is no limit on strcpy() that can be used to prevent overrunning the destination buffer if its end is reached before the null-terminator is found in the source: UB.

Comment: Oh look, a downvote.  Oh dear, my answer must be wrong:(   I will be sure to use strcpy() in future for copying arrays. especially those containing binary data with embedded nulls and those with no guaranteed null termination, since it's sure to work just fine.  My bad.:(

Comment: Don't worry, mate. Have an upboat.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. In my situation, I know exactly how long the strong is though, and it has a null terminator, so sounds like all is good